# @Startup for EJBs not available for EJBs in Liberty Profile?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-liberty

in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSRTLW_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_restrict.html I see:

> cdi-1.0 feature restrictions The supported entry point into CDI is
>   through an expression language lookup of an @Named CDI style bean,
>   with other CDI beans injected into it. The following CDI Integration
>   points are not available or have limited availability: @Startup
>   Enterprise Java Beans in CDI enabled modules.

Does this mean this annotation is silently ignored and EJBs with it will need to be injected somewhere to start its lifecycle?

Is there any workaround to have EJBs to auto startup without being @Inject'ed or @EJB'ed in another component?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this restriction is saying that using `@Inject` to inject CDI beans into an EJB annotated with `@Startup` might not work as expected with the cdi-1.0 feature.  The `@Startup` annotation within the EJB container should work fine otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The restriction is a kind of out-of-date. The @Inject should work on @Startup beans under the cdi-1.0 feature. Please report if it does not work for your scenario. I am trying to get my ID team to update the restriction.